# How to get value from Django view into Ajax success function

Tags: jquery, django, ajax, django-views

I have a django application where a user can upload a file on form submit. When the file is uploaded the program will get the column names from the csv file and display that in the Django Template

This is my views

```
def handle_new_file(request):
    if (request.method == 'POST'):
        form = NewFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            csv_file = request.FILES['csv_file']

            fs = FileSystemStorage()
            file_name = fs.save(csv_file.name, csv_file)
            file_url = f"./media/file_uploads/{file_name}"
            
            print(file_name)
            print(file_url)
            
            cols = get_column_names(file_url)
            form.save()

        return HttpResponse(cols)
```

While the above view is called successfully on form submit, I am not able to pass this `cols` data back to the template. Here is my Ajax code

```
function upload(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = new FormData($('form').get(0));

    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
}

$(function () {
    $('#new_form').submit(upload);
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What if you use a `return JsonResponse({'cols': cols})`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem get this output `[object Object]` in the alert.

Comment: @Sahaank and what if you use `alert(data.cols)`?

Comment: @Sahaank: it is probably better for debugging to make use of `console.log(data.cols)`. It will print the data in the console that you can probably access with Ctrl+Shift+I in the browser.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Nothing seems to be logged in the console.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Sorry. I forgot to refresh the page. `data.cols` seems to work perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of a [**`JsonResponse`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) where you return the result as a JSON blob:

```
def handle_new_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            csv_file = request.FILES['csv_file']

            fs = FileSystemStorage()
            file_name = fs.save(csv_file.name, csv_file)
            file_url = f"./media/file_uploads/{file_name}"
            
            print(file_name)
            print(file_url)
            
            cols = get_column_names(file_url)
            form.save()

    return JsonResponse({'cols': cols})
```

then in the AJAX call, you can access the object with:

```
$.ajax({
    # …
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.cols);
    }
});
```

Of course in reality you process `data.cols`, and likely do not log the content of the list.